# How to project point in Graphics3D to the plane of the screen?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, projection

The code bellow depicts two black points `{0,0,0}` and `{2,1,-1/2}`. Projection of the point `{0,0,0}` to the plane of the screen is `{1/2,1/2}` which is defined in `Epilog` and can be seen as red point.

```
Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[20], Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, -1/2}}]}, 
 SphericalRegion -> Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Boxed -> False, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{0.5, 0.5}]}, {Green, 
    AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{0.87, 0.383}]}}]
```

[image]

What is projection of the second point `{2,1,-1/2}` to the plane of the screen? I need exact formula for it computation.

I found manually that it is approximately `{0.87, 0.383}` - green point.

For computation of the projection it is necessary to know `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical`. Default values are `ViewVertical->{0,0,1}` and `ViewPoint->{1.3, -2.4, 2.}` but I need the formula for any values of these parameters.

Comment: You'll need to extract the `ViewMatrix` somehow, maybe it should be `Dynamic`. Then use that to do the projection.

Comment: Projection point g into the screenplane(3D) : `b[g_]:=n.n/(n.(g-ViewPoint))(g-ViewPoint)-n` (n: ViewCenter-ViewPoint) . ViewPoint and ViewCenter in global 3D coordinates(not scaled) . `b[ViewCenter]={0,0,0}`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Can you make an answer of it? I do not see how it works, what is `n`, etc...

Comment: @azerbajdzan It is only a first step to describe the projection in a  plane perpendicular to n. As I wrote in my comment `n=ViewCenter-ViewPoint`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Output of `b[g]` is some kind of matrix not a point in 3D or 2D.

Comment: @azerbajdzan It gives a vector . You have to give values for viewpoint and viewcenter!